# No available video device' when compiling with CMake

Tags: c, linux, cmake, sdl-2, clion

I can compile my code using Makefile and it works fine. When I try to run same code compiled with Cmake `SDL_GetError()` says:

> 'No available video device'

I think something wrong with my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD  90)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

project(RTv1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

set(SOURCES ...)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

get_filename_component(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR_PARENT ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} DIRECTORY)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
        )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR_PARENT}
        )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

Running Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa, self-built SDL2 in project's libsdl/ folder, findSDL works fine, compilation successfull, Clion 2019.3.3

Comment: My best guess is that your self-built SDL2 don't have any video support, but your makefile links with other (e.g. system-provided) libSDL2 that does. You can check with `ldd`. If you can't find it, please attach ldd output for both binaries and makefile and/or make output for linking.

Comment: @keltar seems like you are right! I thought I deleted all SDL packages but it turned out I left one. Makefile was linking to that lib somehow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some uninstalled dependencies, this helped:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential mercurial make cmake autoconf automake \
libtool libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libaudio-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev \
libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxxf86vm-dev \
libxss-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libgles2-mesa-dev \
libegl1-mesa-dev libibus-1.0-dev fcitx-libs-dev libsamplerate0-dev \
libsndio-dev libwayland-dev libxkbcommon-dev
```